# Getting access to Ember ApplicationController from another view

Tags: ember.js

I would like to init a list of all users in ApplicationController and then show them in dropdown in another view. How can I get access to the ApplicationController from different views?

Here is relevant code:

```
  App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   setupController:function(controller) {
    controller.set('users', App.User.find());
    controller.set('selectedUser', null);
  }
 });

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
   {{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="App.ApplicationController.users"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
   selectionBinding="App.ApplicationControllerselectedUser"}}

   selected user: {{App.ApplicationController.selectedUser.fullName}}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Specify `needs` in your view's controller

```
App.UsersController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application']
});
```

In your view you can then access the application controller as follows

```
controllers.application
```

In your example

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
  {{view Ember.Select
         contentBinding="controllers.application.users"
         optionValuePath="content.id"
         optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
         selectionBinding="controllers.application.selectedUser"}}

  selected user: {{controllers.application.selectedUser.fullName}}
</script>
```

Comment: Crazy, that didn't show up when I used `{{debugger}}`, i.e. `this.controllers` returned `null`. But it works now!

Comment: That is because ``this`` in context of the template is equivalent to ``controller``. which can be proven by printing constructors, like: ````{{this.constructor}}    // App.ApplicationController
{{controller.constructor}}  // App.ApplicationController:ember````

Answer (score 2):

You can look for the controller via the container

```
this.container.lookup('controller:application')
```